# ¿Por qué obtengo el error CannotResolveClassException al deserializar XML?

Tags: java, xstream

`Eclipse` me da un error en consola y cuando pincho en el enlace para ver dónde ha fallado me redirige a una pantalla de información donde me indica que la fuente de la librería no existe.

Si pulso en cambiar fuente adjunta me abre un cuadro de diálogo donde me ofrece el listado de librerías instaladas. Localizo la que necesito, la selecciono pero no me la coge y continua diciéndome que no dispongo de la librería cuando si que la tengo importada en el proyecto.

¿Podríais orientarme con esta cuestión?.

Añado stacktrace

[image: captura_3]

Añado código de la función:

```
public static void autoload_Config_xml() {
    String PATH;
    Config c=new Config ();



    try {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        Annotations.configureAliases(xstream, Registered_user.class);

        PATH = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath()
                + "/src/ejer_tema_4/Utilities/Config/Config.xml";

        File path = new File(PATH);

        if (path.exists()) {
            //Singleton.registered_users = (ArrayList<Registered_user>) xstream.fromXML(new FileReader(PATH));
            //Singleton_Config.config=(Config)xstream.fromXML(new FileReader(PATH));
            c=(Config)xstream.fromXML(new FileReader(PATH));
            Config.setInstance(c);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reading error reg_users.xml", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Añado stacktrace que surge despues de incluir en codigo las sugerencias de Luiggi Mendoza:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : input contained no data
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:80)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:137)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:130)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:109)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:94)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:48)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppDriver.createReader(XppDriver.java:44)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:853)
at ejer_tema_4.Utilities.Config.Config_func.autoload_Config_xml(Config_func.java:90)
at ejer_tema_4.Mains.Main_menu.main(Main_menu.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:63)
... 9 more
```

Comment: Te recomiendo trabajar que trabajes con maven o gradle que te ayudan más con el manejo de las librerías y sus versiones por sobre hacer este trabajo de manera manual.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Si no pasa nada este es el último proyecto con Eclipse, de todas maneras grácias por la recomendación.

Comment: Podrías agregar un poco de código de como usas Xstream por favor Sergio?

Comment: Si te entiendo, tu problema real es por que aparece esa excepción `CannotResolveClassException` (2da imagen) y lo que intentas es ver en qué parte del código aparece tratando de acceder al código de xstream pero cuando haces eso te sale que no existen fuentes para esa librería (1ra imagen). ¿Es esto correcto?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Si Luiggi, asi es.

Comment: Ok, lo que sucede es que efectivamente has agregado la librería de XStream a tu proyecto y ella funciona y se ejecuta correctamente. El problema de la 1ra imagen significa que solo has agregado la dependencia vía una librería compilada, pero no has agregado las fuentes, por ello no puedes ver el código de XStream. Esto no es un problema a menos que realmente quieras navegar por las fuentes de XStream. Pero ten en mente que revisar ese código no resolverá tu problema real: `CannotResolveClassException`.

Comment: @Elenasys. Elena te comento, utilizo el Xstream para guardar la configuración de la aplicación en un archivo XML. Voy a colgar la imagen de la funcion de autocargado de la misma.

Comment: Para que te ayudemos a resolver esa excepción, sería mejor que compartas el código (**texto, no imagen por favor**) donde inicializas y configuras `XStream` y su uso para serializar/deserializar objetos. Precisamente, de acuerdo al stacktrace, debería estar en `ejer_tema4.Utilities.Config.Config_func#autoload_Config_xml`

Comment: Os paso también el codigo de la clase configuración?

Comment: La pregunta está mal formulada, lo que tienes aquí es una implementación incorrecta de una serialización/deserialización de documentos XML con Xstream, especificamente con una clase que has llamado Config en la línea 88 debes ubicar el código conflictivo.

Answer (score 1):

En esta línea

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
    Annotations.configureAliases(xstream, Registered_user.class);
```

en lugar de `Registered_user.class` coloca `Config.class` que es lo que realmente quieres procesar.

Saludos,

Comment: Bueno esto es embarazoso, deberia haber revisado el codigo, porque en realidad donde pone Registered_user.class deberia poner Config.class, pero si no lo he hecho es porque, (no os lo vais a creer), en la version anterior funciona con el Registered_user.

Answer (score 0):

He aquí el problema: no estás configurando la clase `Config` para ser serializada/deserializada por XStream:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
Annotations.configureAliases(xstream, Registered_user.class);
//...
c=(Config)xstream.fromXML(new FileReader(PATH));
```

Al parecer tu xml posee la siguiente forma:

```
<config>
    <!-- contenido del XML -->
</config>
```

Y XStream no tiene mapeado cómo transformar un elemento `<config>` a una clase en particular. Para resolver esto, agrega la configuración relevante para este caso:

```
xstream.alias(Config.class.getSimpleName(), Config.class);
```

O utilizando el método que tienes arriba:

```
Annotations.configureAliases(xstream, Config.class);
```

Comment: He sustituido Registered_user.class por Config.class y he probado tambien cambiar Annotations.configureAliases(xstream, Config.class); por xstream.alias(Config.class.getSimpleName(), Config.class); y el da otro error que posteo a continuacion.

Answer (score -1):

Sigue estos pasos:

1. Boton derecho en el proyecto al que quieras añadir la libreria. Opcion <kbd>Properties...</kbd>
2. Selecciona **`Java Build Path`** en el menu lateral

   - Si el jar esta en el workspace <kbd>Add JARs...</kbd>
   - Si el jar esta un directorio externo <kbd>Add External JARs...</kbd>
3. Selecciona el jar en el explorador que se abra y listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después ya podrás usar la libreria en tus clases.

Comment: Ahí esta la cuestión, abro el Java Build Path y en la pestaña de librerías aparece la librería que luego me dice que no está. Si pulso Add JARs no me ofrece librerías para importar dentro de mi proyecto pues las que tengo ya están todas importadas. También he intentado importarlas de manera externa pero el error es el mismo. La librería esta importada pero no la reconoce.

Comment: descarga el `jar` a mano, y exportalo desde un directorio externo al workspace, cuando lo veas en `Referenced Libraries` podrás usarlo en el proyecto.

Comment: He seguido tus indicaciones, a saber , he descargado de nuevo la librería, la he guardado en un fichero externo. He borrado las librerías existentes de igual nombre e importado la ultima descargada desde la carpeta externa. Ejecuto y el mensaje de error persiste.

Comment: ¿Por cierto en que parte se encuentra Referenced Libraries?

Comment: @sergio he colgado una nueva imagen con referenced libraries resaltado, postea tambien tu error y stacktrace porfi!

Comment: Acabo de incluir una imagen del stacktrace en la pregunta, en cuanto al error no se muy bien a que te refieres. Cuando ejecuto me sale la consola indicando el error.

Comment: Hay que observar un detalle, cuando una librearía no es reconocida a través de classpath; el código simplemente no compila y en el IDE debe subrayarse con rojo ¿te sucede?, si no te sucede, entonces creo que no es tema de imports de librerías si no mas bien errores en tiempo de ejecución. Nos confirmas? Porque veo un `Exception in thread main` o sea que lo estas ejecutando o sea que compila.